# problem with calling invalidate in async task thread in Android !

Tags: android, android-asynctask, invalidation

I am trying to call the invalidate() from asyntask thread. I am getting this error :

> 10-18 15:14:30.469: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(889): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

The line I have used is :

> mainClass.myMapView.invalidate();//where mainClass=main UI class

Can anyone kindly suggest where my fault is ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything UI-related from a different thread than the UI thread (thus its name). You should call `invalidate()` in either `onPostExecute()` or in `onProgress()`. Or, use [runOnUiThread()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) (which is basically what `publishProgress()` / `onProgress()` does).