# How to refresh image view immediately

Tags: android, multithreading, image

In my android app, I download an image from the cloud. The download is performed in a thread and in that same thread I also set an image view with the newly downloaded image. After setting the image, I then call `postinvalidate()`.

However the image does not immediately show up. Is there a way to make the redraw happen immediately? I need a way to trigger a drawing cycle.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Each class which is derived from the View class has the `invalidate()` and the `postInvalidate()` method. If `invalidate()` gets called it tells the system that the current view has changed and it should be redrawn **as soon as possible**. As this method can only be called from your **UIThread** another method is needed for when you are **not** in the **UIThread** and still want to notify the system that your View has been changed. The `postInvalidate()` method notifies the system from a **non-UIThread** and the View gets redrawn in the **next eventloop** on the UIThread as soon as possible.

In your case you can achieve what you want with the help of `AsyncTask` (an intelligent backround thread).AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations (download image in background in your case) and publish results (set your bitmap to your ImageView) on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by **3 generic types**, called Params, Progress and Result, and **4 steps**, called begin, doInBackground, processProgress and end, as explained in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The 4 steps
>
> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> `onPreExecute()`, invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task
> is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for
> instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface before
> downloading the image from cloud and that's used to provide a good
> user experience .
>
> `doInBackground(Params...)`, invoked on the background thread
> immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call
> to `publishProgress(Progress...)`. The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>
> `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background
> computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
> passed to this step as a parameter in that method you can set the
> bitmap to your imageView and invalidate your views

Answer (score 5):

Invalidate doesn't work. Changing the uri or url or the path of the image temporarily and changing back to the required path works. For example, if i have

```
image_url="myhost/img.png";
himg.setImageURI(image_url, imageLoader);
```

I can refresh this as:

```
 himg.setImageURI(null, imageLoader);
 himg.setImageURI(image_url, imageLoader)
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)? It forces the view to be redrawn immediately and not during the next cycle

Comment: I haven't tried right now, but it seems you can do so when in `onPostExecute()`. See a reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960886/problem-with-calling-invalidate-in-async-task-thread-in-android)

Comment: Oh, I see your problem now. I was expecting all the time you were using `AsyncTask`. My fault, sorry

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    imgArray = receiveImagebytes();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgArray, 0, imgArray.length));
                    imageView.invalidate();
                }
            });
```