# Getting a reference to a Dialogfragment in Android

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Scenario: I have a dialog fragment. Onclick of an image it launches an activity which does the  process in an asynctask. When I get back the result the activity finishes and goes back to the dialog fragment.On getting back the image must be changed.

Problem:The image remains the same and only when you close the dialogfragment and reopen it does it change.

Sorry I havnt posted the code, Just wanted some suggestions on how to update the view from the activitys async task.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, try use [invalidate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894378/3903464) method for your ImageView in **onPostExecute()** of your *AsyncTask*.
If you start your *AsyncTask* in launched *Activity*, as I suppose, you can start custom Activity in Dialog Fragment and pass your ImageView pointer to constructor. Something like this.

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity{

    private ImageView yourImage;

    public AsyncTaskActivity(ImageView yourImage){
           this.yourImage = yourImage;
    }
    ....
    //your AsyncTask should be like this
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        //here your backround process
        ...
        //here we invalidate ImageView
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                  //update image Bitmap or something else
                  ...
                  yourImage.invalidate();
        }   
    }.execute();
}
```

With best regards.

Comment: Can you explain how i can invalidate the dialogfragment view from activities asynctask.

Comment: @user2769567 I've updated my answer. If something remains unclear ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Start the activity (B) by using startActivityForResult from your dialog.
2. Override OnActivityResult in your original activity (A, the one that host the dialog).
3. call super.OnAcitivityResult in it, so that the dialog can receive the call back.
4. Your dialogfragment should override OnActivityResult and change the image based on the result.

Need your code to see what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I tried that but since its running in an asynctask there is a delay in getting the response by which time the dialogfragment is up