# Image not changing in ImageView

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso

I am making a demo in android for imageLoading, I have used first `UniversalImageLoader` then `picasso` and then an `ImageLoader` class,But all times when i upload a new image to server and it successful uploaded to server and when i am trying to set it to `ImageView` ,the previously loaded image is remains same,its not changing,I am so frustrated by this and wasted 2 days to solve this with no luck,Please help me to save my life.

my code is as below:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(Pref.getValue(getApplicationContext(),
                    Const.PREF_PROFILE_PIC, "")).into(iv_profile);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(Pref.getValue(getApplicationContext(),
                    Const.PREF_COVER_PIC, "")).into(iv_cover);
```

Comment: Picasso, UniversalImageLoader or any other image loading libraries are using image caching to reload image. so either you need to change the name of new image or clear image cache to load new image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893826/how-to-refresh-image-view-immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `cachebreaker` at the end of the url:

```
String imageurl1 = Const.PREF_PROFILE_PIC + "?" + new Date().getTime();
String imageurl2 = Const.PREF_COVER_PIC + "?" + new Date().getTime();

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load(Pref.getValue(getApplicationContext(),
                imageurl1, "")).into(iv_profile);

Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load(Pref.getValue(getApplicationContext(),
                imageurl2, "")).into(iv_cover);
```

This will append the current timestamp automatically when you are creating the image, and it will make the browser look again for the image instead of retrieving the one in the cache.

Comment: Thank you neeraj for your reply,But i am getting this image url from server,So i cant change the url.Any other solution?please please .i will wait for your reply

Comment: cant you modify the imageurl?

Comment: oh my godd...You are genius mann...!!Thanks a lot,,You saved my day...Neeraj god bless..!!!

Comment: i learned something today. Thanks for that `cachebreaker` / `cache buster` thing @KNeerajLal

Answer (score 0):

the idea is same as above. but it didnt worked for me.

I got the answer from this [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/438)

change your URL as shown below:

```
String imageurl = url + "?time=" + System.currentTimeMillis();
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageurl).into(imageView);
```

this worked for me. thanks