# Load Image File to Image View

Tags: java, android, xml

So, I'm (still) trying to build a simple camera app and what I have so far is an Image Controller which is able to take a picture, save it into the storage and pass the filepath with an intent to another activity.

In my new activity the first step I'm tying to achieve is, to get my final Image loaded into an ImageView, so I did the following:

```
    ImageView finalImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after);

        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        String filePath = getIntent.getExtras().getString("filePath");

        File imgFile = new File(filePath);

        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            finalImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.finalImage);
            finalImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
```

But, its not working, and I dont quite unterstand why not... :( The Activity starts completely fine, but the ImageView just does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does the app crash? If yes, post the logcat as well.

Comment: Can you define "not working" please? Add a crash log if it crashes

Comment: No, just nothing happens. The activity starts fine, but the ImageView does nothing.

Comment: Where are you asking for the Storage Permission?

Comment: @MohammedAtif In another activity, but this isn't the problem, since I figured out, it does work, if a throw in a hardcoded filepath to a random image file. But it doesnt if I use the filepath string variable of the image i just shot and now I'm officially completely confused.

Comment: Why dont you add a log after this line `String filePath = getIntent.getExtras().getString("filePath");` and see whether you are actually passing the correct image value or not.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Well, I did try to pass the String into a textView to check wether its correct or not, and yes, the filepath is completely correct.

Comment: If you are using TextView instead of logs to debug the issue, Then definitely you are in very begninning stage of development. So please can you share the code where you are saving the file after capturing the image and then calling this new Activity. I think the click and save process is faulty if you are saying that your code is working for hardcoded files.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Well yes, I definitely am. You can find my whole sourcecode on [github](https://github.com/bennistrati/iDrone), if you want to have a look at it. But I dont think the save progress is faulty, since I just figured out, my code is working if I dont immediately try to load the image in the onCreate method, but pass it into another method, which then gets called with a button.

Comment: As expected, your image saving process is faulty.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Oh. Well, and how do I fix that?

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you must know in the process of saving Image in Android

`ccv2WithPreview.takePicture();`

In this line the method executed is

```
public void takePicture() {
    try {
        // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
        mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In this method, capture() call is asynchronous. Since you are ending the activity soon after calling it and starting new Activity, so by the time your code saves the Image in Image Saver, you are starting new Activity already and your file is not yet ready.

You button implementation works because by the time you click button, Image will be saved.

To solve this problem,

**CameraHelper.java**

```
public interface CameraHelper{
    void fileSaved(String filePath);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SensorEventListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, CameraHelper{
    ...
    @Override
    public void fileSaved(String file){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AfterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("filePath", file);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

in onCreate of MainActivity

```
ccv2WithPreview = new CameraControllerV2WithPreview(MainActivity.this, textureView, MainActivity.this);
```

in your camera class

```
private CameraHelper cameraHelper; //Initialize in constructor
```

Then in ImageSaver

```
private boolean imageSaved = false;
public void run() {
    if(!imageSaved) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mFile)) {
            output.write(bytes);
            imageSaved = true;
            cameraHelper.fileSaved(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you must handle any Asynchronous tasks you get in future. Callback based implementations.

Comment: Well, I do have another question regarding your solution. With `cameraHelper.fileSaved(mFile);` you pass a file into the fileSaved function, while the function expexts a String. But when i tried to pass my filePath String instead i get a nullpointer exception...

Comment: are you using `mFile.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: I updated the answer for more robust file handling, but you have to make sure that file is not null when it is passed to constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll have a look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to `invalidate()` the ImageView after setting the bitmap?

(I'm pretty much guessing here, but working with GUIs a couple of years ago, i remember that if a view changed you have to tell the view to about it, so that it can be redrawn.)

Please also see: [How to refresh image view immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893826/how-to-refresh-image-view-immediately)